# Using segues to pass data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to use segues to pass the data entered in the partyID text field to the partyID label in a separate view controller. However, I am getting errors in my code.

```
class PartyViewController: UIViewController {

    // CALLS LOGIN VC
    var LoginViewController: LoginViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var partyID: UITextField!

    var token = String()

    @IBAction func startParty(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "partyVCtoGuestPartyVC", sender: self)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "hostStartParty", sender: self)
        //LoginViewController?.fetchSpotifyProfile(accessToken )

        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
               if(segue.identifier == "partyVCtoGuestPartyVC"){
               let GuestPartyVC = segue.destination as! GuestPartyViewController
               GuestPartyVC.partyID = partyID.text
           }
```

And here is the view controller I am trying to pass the data to:

```
class GuestPartyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var partyID: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        partyIDLabel.text = partyID
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

I get errors in my override func in LoginVC and then in the partyIDlabel.text in the GuestPartyVC.

Comment: What errors? At least `prepare(for segue` must be on the same level as `viewDidLoad` outside of the `IBAction`. And why do you perform two segues simultaneously?

Comment: After doing a combination of the answers on this page I get a thread1 error: SIGABRT in appdelegate

Comment: setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Answer (score 1):

**In GuestPartyViewController**

```
class GuestPartyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var partyIDLabel: UILabel!

    var partyID: String? 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        partyIDLabel.text = partyID ?? ""
    }
}
```

**In PartyViewController**

```
class PartyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var partyID: UITextField!


    @IBAction func startParty(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "partyVCtoGuestPartyVC", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "partyVCtoGuestPartyVC",
            let GuestPartyVC = segue.destination as? GuestPartyViewController {
            GuestPartyVC.partyID = partyID.text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After doing a combination of the answers on this page I get a thread1 error: SIGABRT in appdelegate

Comment: setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Comment: Make sure your class names updated correctly, also your segue identifier "partyVCtoGuestPartyVC" is updated in storyboard.. might be a small spelling mistake

Answer (score 0):

The IBOutlet is weak and may not be instantiate when you pass the text.

Could you try to pass the text in a property, then assign it in the viewDidLoad ?

```
class GuestPartyViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var partyID: UILabel!

var passedText: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   if let unwrappedPassedText = passedText {
      partyIDLabel.text = partyID
   }
}
```

// In the other controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "partyVCtoGuestPartyVC") {
        let GuestPartyVC = segue.destination as! GuestPartyViewController
        GuestPartyVC.passedText = partyID.text
    }
```

Comment: After doing a combination of the answers on this page I get a thread1 error: SIGABRT in appdelegate

Comment: setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Answer (score 0):

first change the call of login VC

```
var LoginViewController = LoginViewController()
```

then put this before the view did load method

```
@IBOutlet weak var partyID: UITextField!
```

and can you send the error that you get

Comment: After doing a combination of the answers on this page I get a thread1 error: SIGABRT in appdelegate

Comment: setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key